# Read file using awk and iterated over array with nested loop

Tags: arrays, bash, awk

I tried to iterate over two arrays (with two nested for loops) using bash.
Unfortunatly bash is really slow by iterating over large arrays. So I tried to use awk.

- First

  I am reading in two files (around 200.000 lines) and take the tab seperated column I wanna use

  `START=($(awk -F'\t' '{print $5}' $inputGenes))`

I was always thinking that START is now something like an array, but right now I'm not sure any more.
I have a lot of different "arrays" and go to the next step

- Second

  Everything is working fine with small files and not using awk, but a normal nested bash loop.
  Now I was trying to use awk and I fail.
  The two variables $len and $varlen are indicating the size of two arrays (read in like before using awk)

  `len=${#posVCF[@]}`

The loops are working but I get no output, because it is not possible to get the information out of the arrays : $posVCF[$i] returns nothing. But I have no idea how to get information out of my arrays variables.

```
**echo | awk 'BEGIN {for(i=1; i -st $len; i++) {
                        for (j=1; j -st $varlen; j++) {
                                if ($posVCF[$i] -gt $START[$j] && $posVCF[$i] -st $END[$j]) {
                                        print $posVCF[$i] " > " $START[$j] " und < " $END[$j]
                                }
                         }
                      }
            }'**
```

Am I doing something wrong by reading the files or do you have any ideas? I'm really new in programming in bash, but I have to write in bash.
I hope you can help me, thank you very much.

Comment: Please, show us a sample of your input file, and a respective expected output. This way, it is easier to grasp the meaning of your explanations, and therefore give you an appropriate answer.

Comment: I suspect you're approach is completely wrong. Post some sample input and expected output so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You need braces to dereference an array element. Not `$posVCF[$i]` but `${posVCF[$i]}` is correct.

---

I misread your question. Why do you think you need awk? All your variables are in the shell. You can use C-like [for loops in bash](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-for):

```
for ((i=1; i < len; i++)); do
    for ((j=1; j < varlen; j++)); do
        if (( ${posVCF[$i]} > ${START[$j]} && ${posVCF[$i]} < ${END[$j]} )); then
            echo ${posVCF[$i]} " > " ${START[$j]} " und < " ${END[$j]}
        fi
    done
done
```

This is using the bash arithmetic evaluation syntax: `(( ... ))`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried it, but than following error occures: 
awk: cmd. line:4:                               if (${posVCF[$i]} -gt ${START[$j]} && ${posVCF[$i]} -st ${END[$j]}) {
awk: cmd. line:4:                                    ^ syntax error

Do you have any idea what I am doing wrong?